# Redirect to a new URL based on a flag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to redirect all the request to my Ruby on Rails website to a new URL with the same params based on a flag. Based on the flag, the user should be

1.redirected to errorpage
 2.redirected to new url
 3.request handled by same server.

Putting the redirection logic in  before_filter of application_controller results in a cyclic dependency when redirected to errorpage.

```
class ApplicationController
  before_filter :redirect_if_old

  def redirect_if_old
    flag = get_from_rules_engine # The value is obtained from a rules engine
    if(flag == 1)
        redirect_to errorpage_path
    else
        if (flag == 2)
            redirect_to "https:new-url#{request.fullpath}", :status => :moved_permanently
        end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: try adding some code next time.

Comment: We cannot possibly see the issue with your code, without actually seeing it. Please see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry, added the code now.

Comment: Where is `flag` defined? Is it defined on the `errorpage_path` too?

Comment: Actually flag is something which I get from a rules engine, so that it can be changed when the application is up and running without a deployment. I have simplified that with a flag here in the code.

Comment: is it going into loop for flag 1/2?

Answer (score 0):

Try the `return` as shown below:

```
class ApplicationController
  before_filter :redirect_if_old

  def redirect_if_old
    if(flag == 1)
        redirect_to errorpage_path and return
    else
        if (flag == 2)
            redirect_to "https:new-url#{request.fullpath}" and return, :status => :moved_permanently 
        end
    end
  end
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue. I am still getting circular dependency.